# What does this HERE maps error mean?

Tags: java-me, here-api

I am developing an app using the [HERE maps api](http://developer.here.com/). I copied and pasted the code I found [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/HERE_Maps_Java_ME/#!quick-start.html) since I wanted to get a feel for how to use the api. Here's the `startApp()` method

```
protected void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {
    System.err.println("1st line of midlet");
    ApplicationContext.getInstance().setAppID("my id here");        
    ApplicationContext.getInstance().setToken("my token here");
    System.err.println("before display");
    Display display = Display.getDisplay(this);     
    MapCanvas mapCanvas = new MapCanvas(display){           
        public void onMapUpdateError(String description,Throwable detail, boolean critical) {               
            // Error handling goes here.            
        }           
        public void onMapContentComplete() {            
        }
    };  
    mapCanvas.getMapDisplay().setState(new MapDisplayState(new GeoCoordinate(52.51, 13.4, 0), 10));     
    display.setCurrent(mapCanvas);
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

- java.lang.Class.invoke_verify(), bci=0
- java.lang.Class.initialize(), bci=100
- java.lang.Class.forName(), bci=0
- com.sun.midp.main.CldcMIDletLoader.newInstance(), bci=1
- com.sun.midp.midlet.MIDletStateHandler.createMIDlet(), bci=63
- com.sun.midp.midlet.MIDletStateHandler.createAndRegisterMIDlet(), bci=17
- com.sun.midp.midlet.MIDletStateHandler.startSuite(), bci=24
- com.sun.midp.main.AbstractMIDletSuiteLoader.startSuite(), bci=38
- com.sun.midp.main.CldcMIDletSuiteLoader.startSuite(), bci=5
- com.sun.midp.main.AbstractMIDletSuiteLoader.runMIDletSuite(), bci=151
- com.sun.midp.main.AppIsolateMIDletSuiteLoader.main(), bci=26

What is the problem? Please help me in understanding the actual cause of this error.

I've been trying all sort of things for 3 hours now.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It is nothing to do with the API - the MIDlet hasn't started yet - the app is failing when trying to start up. If you a quick online search for `com.sun.midp.main.CldcMIDletLoader.newInstance()` you find instances of similar problems such as [this](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/eclipse-running-error-for-samsung-sdk/81/97087), which suggests that the issue is with your midlet configuration.

So either follow the advice here:

> I had almost the same error. My problem solved when set the correct
>   name and class in application descriptor editor (in eclipse of course)
>
> Open the project jad file and fill the correct information in Midlets
>   tab. (Your midlet name and class name)

Or restart by using the code from the associated [code examples](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/HERE_Maps_Java_ME/#!code-examples.html) which already has correctly configured application descriptors for both Eclipse and Netbeans. I guess it is likely that you have downloaded the examples anyway, as they form part of  the [Asha SDK 1.0 Beta](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/asha/java/downloads.xhtml) download. In this case you should find them under `C:\Nokia\Devices\Nokia_Asha_SDK_1_0\plugins\maps api\example`.

Comment: I just tried reducing the code, just to debug it properly. None of your suggestions worked. I tried runnning the examples that come with the SDK, I got the exception `ClassFormatError: Invalid version in .class file`. I didn't change anything on them. I now seem to have a bigger problem. I removed the `MapCanvas` part of the code and left `ApplicationContext.getInstance()` part --- It seems to be generating an error. Here's the [error](http://pastebay.net/1239588)

Comment: That is still a bootstrapping error. The minimal map code can be found [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/HERE_Maps_Java_ME/#!quick-start.html). Try making sure you have correctly followed the **Configuring the IDE** section for your IDE. and check that your IDE is one of the following  - _Nokia IDE for Java ME (Eclipse) v2_, 
_Eclipse Indigo with Mobile Tools for Java (MTJ)_ or _NetBeans 7.0 or later_. I'd suggest the Nokia IDE gives the smoothest experience.